# C# Reflection: Fastest Way to Update a Property Value?

Tags: c#, performance, reflection, properties

Is this the fastest way to update a property using reflection? Assume the property is always an int:

```
PropertyInfo counterPropertyInfo = GetProperty();
int value = (int)counterPropertyInfo.GetValue(this, null);
counterPropertyInfo.SetValue(this, value + 1, null);
```

Comment: I see that you pass _this_ as the instance. Why don't you just set the property directly?

Comment: The fastest way would be such classes implement an IIncrementable interface and use it and not reflection

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just be sure that you are caching the PropertyInfo somehow, so that you aren't repeatably calling type.GetProperty. Other than that it would probably be faster if you created a delegate to a method on the type that performed the increment, or like Teoman suggested make the type implement an interface and use that.

Answer (score 27):

I did some [benchmarking here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10820453/reflection-performance-create-delegate-properties-c) when you know the type arguments (a non generic approach wont be very different). `CreateDelegate` would be the fastest approach for a property if you can't directly access it. With `CreateDelegate` you get a direct handle to `GetGetMethod` and `GetSetMethod` of the `PropertyInfo`, hence reflection is not used every time.

```
public static Func<S, T> BuildGetAccessor<S, T>(Expression<Func<S, T>> propertySelector)
{
    return propertySelector.GetPropertyInfo().GetGetMethod().CreateDelegate<Func<S, T>>();
}

public static Action<S, T> BuildSetAccessor<S, T>(Expression<Func<S, T>> propertySelector)
{
    return propertySelector.GetPropertyInfo().GetSetMethod().CreateDelegate<Action<S, T>>();
}

// a generic extension for CreateDelegate
public static T CreateDelegate<T>(this MethodInfo method) where T : class
{
    return Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(T), method) as T;
}

public static PropertyInfo GetPropertyInfo<S, T>(this Expression<Func<S, T>> propertySelector)
{
    var body = propertySelector.Body as MemberExpression;
    if (body == null)
        throw new MissingMemberException("something went wrong");

    return body.Member as PropertyInfo;
}
```

So now you call:

```
TestClass cwp = new TestClass();
var access = BuildGetAccessor((TestClass t) => t.AnyValue);
var result = access(cwp);
```

Or even better you can encapsulate the logic in a dedicated class to have a get and set methods on it.

Something like:

```
public class Accessor<S>
{
    public static Accessor<S, T> Create<T>(Expression<Func<S, T>> memberSelector)
    {
        return new GetterSetter<T>(memberSelector);
    }

    public Accessor<S, T> Get<T>(Expression<Func<S, T>> memberSelector)
    {
        return Create(memberSelector);
    }

    public Accessor()
    {

    }

    class GetterSetter<T> : Accessor<S, T>
    {
        public GetterSetter(Expression<Func<S, T>> memberSelector) : base(memberSelector)
        {

        }
    }
}

public class Accessor<S, T> : Accessor<S>
{
    Func<S, T> Getter;
    Action<S, T> Setter;

    public bool IsReadable { get; private set; }
    public bool IsWritable { get; private set; }
    public T this[S instance]
    {
        get
        {
            if (!IsReadable)
                throw new ArgumentException("Property get method not found.");

            return Getter(instance);
        }
        set
        {
            if (!IsWritable)
                throw new ArgumentException("Property set method not found.");

            Setter(instance, value);
        }
    }

    protected Accessor(Expression<Func<S, T>> memberSelector) //access not given to outside world
    {
        var prop = memberSelector.GetPropertyInfo();
        IsReadable = prop.CanRead;
        IsWritable = prop.CanWrite;
        AssignDelegate(IsReadable, ref Getter, prop.GetGetMethod());
        AssignDelegate(IsWritable, ref Setter, prop.GetSetMethod());
    }

    void AssignDelegate<K>(bool assignable, ref K assignee, MethodInfo assignor) where K : class
    {
        if (assignable)
            assignee = assignor.CreateDelegate<K>();
    }
}
```

Short and simple. You can carry around an instance of this class for every "class-property" pair you wish to get/set.

Usage:

```
Person p = new Person { Age = 23 };
var ageAccessor = Accessor<Person>(x => x.Age);
int age = ageAccessor[p]; //gets 23
ageAccessor[p] = 45; //sets 45
```

Bit bad use of indexers here, you may replace it with dedicated "Get" and "Set" methods, but very intuitive to me :)

To avoid having to specify type each time like,

```
var ageAccessor = Accessor<Person>(x => x.Age);
var nameAccessor = Accessor<Person>(x => x.Name);
var placeAccessor = Accessor<Person>(x => x.Place);
```

I made the base `Accessor<>` class instantiable, which means you can do

```
var personAccessor = new Accessor<Person>();
var ageAccessor = personAccessor.Get(x => x.Age);
var nameAccessor = personAccessor.Get(x => x.Name);
var placeAccessor = personAccessor.Get(x => x.Place);
```

Having a base `Accessor<>` class means you can treat them as one type, for eg,

```
var personAccessor = new Accessor<Person>();
var personAccessorArray = new Accessor<Person>[] 
                          {
                           personAccessor.Get(x => x.Age), 
                           personAccessor.Get(x => x.Name), 
                           personAccessor.Get(x => x.Place);
                          };
```

Comment: This is fantastic!  It is very close to what I'm looking for, but I'm still fuzzy enough on all of this that I can't see the way to the solution.  I've written a generic ToString method that can be passed any object and it will go and return a string consisting of the values of all of the public properties of the object.  It uses PropertyInfo and GetValue to get each property.  It is *slow*. I want to use your methods here, but it appears that I must know the name of the type at compile time. I don't.  How can I adapt it?

Comment: Yes in my case, the object has to be *typed*, not a generic *object*. But do you really not have the *type* with you? Are they all merely *object* ? If you really have to cope with *object*, then you will have to rely on expression trees (I used CreateDelegate) with intermediate casts and like, but it will be still very fast. Something like shown here http://geekswithblogs.net/Madman/archive/2008/06/27/faster-reflection-using-expression-trees.aspx

Comment: I'm not sure if I can understand your **exact** requirement in the scope of comments or even answer you here, but if it warrants, you can make it a question. Don't forget me to notify here in case ;)

Comment: I think your link in the first comment is exactly what I'm looking for.  I want a fast getter on an object whose type I do not know at compiile time.  Thank you!

Comment: If I only have a string with full class name, and property name like MyNameSpace1.X.Y.Z.ClassName, and PropertyName ?

Comment: @Kiquenet you can do it by normal reflection ([see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404523/set-property-value-using-property-name)), but I guess performance is important to you. In that case see the geekswithblog link in comments above which has getters and setters declared like `Func<object, object>` and `Action<object, object>`.

Comment: if he could access those properties (private or not known in compile time) why would he want to looking for a solution using reflection? sorry but your Expression based approach renders useless in this case.

Comment: @TakeMeAsAGuest you are not entirely wrong, but this does find use in very limited cases. For e.g. you can carry around `Accessor<T>` array without causing boxing penalties and later invoke it. It wouldn't be possible to have a generic `Func<S, ?>` collection of accessors for a class unless you use a `Func<S, object>`. Now it needn't use expression trees or reflection for it, right, but I was also showing a way to bypass the `GetValue`, `SetValue` APIs using expression compiling. As I said its trivial to extend my example to act fully like dynamic accessors.

Comment: @TakeMeAsAGuest In that sense you are right, dynamic case finds the most use here. I was basically caught up between two things I was trying to show. Editing this answer has been long overdue :)

Answer (score 16):

You should look at `FastMember` ([nuget](http://www.nuget.org/packages/FastMember), [source code](https://github.com/mgravell/fast-member/)], it's really fast comparing to reflection.

I've tested these 3 implementations:

- [PropertyInfo.SetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xb5dd1f1.aspx)
- [PropertyInfo.SetMethod](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.setmethod(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [FastMember](https://github.com/mgravell/fast-member/)

The benchmark needs a benchmark function:

```
static long Benchmark(Action action, int iterationCount, bool print = true)
{
    GC.Collect();
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    action(); // Execute once before

    sw.Start();
    for (var i = 0; i <= iterationCount; i++)
    {
        action();
    }

    sw.Stop();
    if (print) System.Console.WriteLine("Elapsed: {0}ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    return sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
}
```

A fake class:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public string PropertyA { get; set; }
}
```

Some test methods:

```
private static void Set(string propertyName, string value)
{
    var obj = new ClassA();
    obj.PropertyA = value;
}

private static void FastMember(string propertyName, string value)
{
    var obj = new ClassA();
    var type = obj.GetType();
    var accessors = TypeAccessor.Create(type);
    accessors[obj, "PropertyA"] = "PropertyValue";
}

private static void SetValue(string propertyName, string value)
{
    var obj = new ClassA();
    var propertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
    propertyInfo.SetValue(obj, value);
}

private static void SetMethodInvoke(string propertyName, string value)
{
    var obj = new ClassA();
    var propertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
    propertyInfo.SetMethod.Invoke(obj, new object[] { value });
}
```

The script itself:

```
var iterationCount = 100000;
var propertyName = "PropertyA";
var value = "PropertyValue";

Benchmark(() => Set(propertyName, value), iterationCount);
Benchmark(() => FastMember(propertyName, value), iterationCount);
Benchmark(() => SetValue(propertyName, value), iterationCount);
Benchmark(() => SetMethodInvoke(propertyName, value), iterationCount);
```

> **Results for 100 000 iterations:**
>
> Default setter : 3ms
>
> **FastMember: 36ms**
>
> PropertyInfo.SetValue: 109ms
>
> PropertyInfo.SetMethod: 91ms

Now you can choose yours !!!

Comment: It can not use in private property.

Comment: Thanks for the update but private properties are not supposed to be set from outside the class scope ???

Comment: I was in the process of writing `FastMember` myself :-) when I found this answer. I've used BenchmakrDotNet to measure it against many alternatives like AutoMapper, CasltleDictionaryAdapter, caching the propertyInfo, caching an action to set the property and, of course, hand-coded property assignment. It was only 36% slower than direct property assignments, and three-times faster than the next fastest alternative. So I gave up writing my own and will be using Marc's FastMember thanks to you! Nice.