# How to change visibility of a mid run created picturebox using windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I'd like to make a game where you can press some random generated pictures and I have the name of the picture in a string variable. How can I access the name to change the pictures visibility, or is there another way?

What is mean is this: `VarWithPicturesName.Visible = false;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set property value using property name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404523/set-property-value-using-property-name)

Comment: It's possible to access that `PictureBox` using [Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controls) property (usually by knowing parent container or with recursion) and using `Tag` to hold custom data. Or you can simply have `Dictionary<string, PictureBox>` to map string name to real instance, when creating new control - add it to dictionary.

Comment: @Sinatr thank you very much I was able to solve the problem with the Dictionary solution.